# How to get rid of if statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, polymorphism, decorator

This is a fake implementation of the [bmr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate) calculation which I use in my Ruby on Rails app.

Since the formula is using only metric units I had to somehow convert imperial units to the metric if imperial units are set to be default for the user.

I have come up with this code.

Personally I think there is a lot of code for this kind of small problem. On the contraty, using polymorphism would be over engineering.
Ways to improve this code?

```
require 'ostruct'
require 'delegate'

module BmrCalculator
  class Calculator
    def call(sex = :male, measurement_unit = :metric)
      user = OpenStruct.new(sex: sex, weight: 2, height: 2, measurement_unit: measurement_unit)

      if measurement_unit == :imperial #dont like it
        user = ImperialToMetricDecorator.new(user)
      end

      BmrCalculator.new.bmr(user)
    end

    class BmrCalculator
      def bmr(user)
        if user.sex == :male
          puts user.inspect
          puts 1 * user.weight + 2 * user.height + 3 #this formula works only with metric units
        else
          puts user.inspect
          puts 6 * user.weight + 3 * user.height + 5 #this formula works only with metric units
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class ImperialToMetricDecorator < SimpleDelegator
    def height
      (super * 2.54)
    end

    def weight
      (super / 2.2)
    end
  end

  Calculator.new.call(:male, :metric)
end
```

Comment: Until you "suffer" from if statements, I wouldn't say they're necessarily bad. One of the reasons polymorphism would be good is when you need to add a third/fourth/fifth case. For male and female, it's pretty much guaranteed you won't. On the other hand, if you find that changing an if statement starts to become painful because of new requirements, then go for the design change that makes it easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve your code by using OOP and creating meaningful representations:

```
class Length < Float
end

class Feet < Length
  def to_meters
    ..
  end
end

class Meters < Length
  def to_feet
    ..
  end
end

class Gender < Object
end

class Male < Gender
  def bmr(weight)
    ...
  end
end


class Female < Gender
  def bmr(weight)
    ...
  end
end
```

This may look like a more code, but it's actually much easier to read, test, and maintain.